# Returns one XML row only from odata webservice to datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, web-services, datagridview

Here is the code I have to get XMl from a webservice and then i'm attempting to bind it to a datagridview but I can only get one row.

```
    public  void CreateObject()
    {
          const string ServerURl = "http://services.odata.org/AdventureWorksV3/AdventureWorks.svc/ProductCatalog";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ServerURl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            ds.ReadXml(response.GetResponseStream());
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateObject();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, it's in a winform app

HERE is the code updated after Roman's suggestion, it seems to be throwing an exception at ds.readxml

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace Odata4
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {

    public DataSet ds;
    public DataTable sourcetable;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void CreateObject()
    {
        const string ServerURl = "http://services.odata.org/AdventureWorksV3/AdventureWorks.svc";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ServerURl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            ds.ReadXml(response.GetResponseStream());

            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                {
                    sourcetable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
                }
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = sourcetable;

        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateObject();

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `ds.Tables[0]` you'll only get the first entry of your `DataSet`. Try to loop your tables and add the results to one `DataTable` which would be your source table.

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        sourcetable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
    }
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = sourcetable;
```

Comment: This threw an exception for 

          
                       sourcetable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in OdataIII.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Have you defined `sourcetable`? If you check it in debugger, is it null? Or is something else null?

Comment: Hi Roman I've updated my code, it seems the error is coming for ds.readxml()

Comment: ds is null when i run it through the debugger

Comment: I guess you solved it since you accepted the answer?

Comment: I started getting an input is too large for array exception so I just raised a question about that:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374580/populate-dataset-with-columns-from-xml/35380465#35380465

I didn't want to keep dragging this post with more question, thanks!