# Populate Dataset with columns from XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, web-services, api

Here is what I have so far:

```
public void CreateObject()
{
    const string ServerURl = "http://services.odata.org/northwind/northwind.svc/Customers";

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable sourcetable = new DataTable();

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerURl);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    richTextBox1.AppendText(response.StatusDescription);
    Stream datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(datastream);

    using (StreamReader mySR = new StreamReader(datastream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
    {
        XmlDocument lgnXml = new XmlDocument();
        lgnXml.Load(mySR);
        XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(lgnXml);

        ds.ReadXml(reader);

        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                sourcetable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
            }
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = sourcetable;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateObject();
}
```

When I try to run this I get this error:
 Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table

I'm guessing i have to add column names to the dataset or datatable? Can I do that from XML?

**EDIT Here's the response when I run it using codeninja.sj's method**

```
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|   |                              id                             |       updated        |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| 1 | http://services.odata.org/northwind/northwind.svc/Customers | 2016-02-15T20:21:21Z |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach 1:** You have to define column-names and its data-type while creating the source data-table

```
DataTable sourcetable = new DataTable();
sourcetable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
sourcetable.Columns.Add("ColumnName1", typeof(string));
sourcetable.Columns.Add("ColumnName2", typeof(string));
```

**Approach 2:** Convert the API response as XML objects; and convert the same as data-set

```
string ServerURl = "http://localhost:53835/api/values";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();            
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerURl);
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();            
var datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(datastream);
ds.ReadXml(reader);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; //ds.Tables["properties"] --> Specify your XML Node Name here
```

**Suggestion:** Second approach is better than the first one; Because you can reuse the same code for different API responses

***Note:*** Modify the above code-snippets based on your API response

Comment: I tried the second approach and I only got one line back in the datagridview

Comment: @Sewder, can u share ur API response?

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: @Sewder, Instead of mentioning table index value as ZERO make it as XML Node name what you want to display on your grid-view. I guess, in your case it must be 'Customer'

Comment: I just saw the Northwind API data response, I guess, in your case data-set table index name must be **properties**

Comment: @Sewder, If you like to display all the data-set results in a single grid-view, you will have to manipulate the data-set to retrieve the single data-table. (For that, you could use LINQ JOINS)